# what is the significance of 'CONTAIN' function in oracle.?

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search

```
CREATE TABLE accumtbl 
   (id NUMBER, text VARCHAR2(4000) )

INSERT INTO accumtbl VALUES 
   ( 1, 'the little dog played with the big dog 
      while the other dog ate the dog food');
INSERT INTO accumtbl values 
   (2, 'the cat played with the dog');

CREATE INDEX 
   accumtbl_idx ON accumtbl (text) 
  indextype is ctxsys.context 

SELECT 
   SCORE(1) 
FROM 
   accumtbl 
WHERE 
   CONTAINS (text, 'dog accum Cat', 1) > 0;
```

output :

```
SCORE(1)
6
52
```

how???

i have tried with different values but not able to understand the meaning of parameters and how score is calculated

```
SELECT 
   SCORE(1) 
FROM 
   accumtbl 
WHERE 
   CONTAINS (text, 'dog accum Cat', 1) > 0;
```

output :

```
SCORE(1)
6
52
```

output :

```
SCORE(1)
6
52
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contains is the Oracle Text operator. Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-13F9B749-125B-40FD-9AFD-A636597447D0.htm#CCAPP9136) says:

> When you create an index of type CONTEXT, you must use the CONTAINS operator to enter your query. An index of type CONTEXT is suited for indexing collections of large coherent documents.
>
> With the CONTAINS operator, you can use a number of operators to define your search criteria. These operators enable you to enter logical, proximity, fuzzy, stemming, thesaurus and wildcard searches. With a correctly configured index, you can also enter section searches on documents that have internal structure such as HTML and XML.
>
> With CONTAINS, you can also use the ABOUT operator to search on document themes.

Furthermore:

> The CONTAINS operator must always be followed by the > 0 syntax, which specifies that the score value returned by the CONTAINS operator must be greater than zero for the row to be returned.
>
> When the SCORE operator is called in the SELECT statement, the CONTAINS operator must reference the score label value in the third parameter

---

I think you're confused with numbers written in both `SCORE` and `CONTAINS` - they should match. Think of them as if they were "labels".

A more "complex" example might be this:

```
SQL> SELECT SCORE (1) sc1,
  2         SCORE (2) sc2
  3    FROM accumtbl
  4   WHERE    CONTAINS (text, 'dog accum Cat', 1) > 0        --> this "1" comes from "score (1)"
  5         OR CONTAINS (text, 'little dog'   , 2) > 0        --> this "2" comes from "score (2)"
  6  ;

       SC1        SC2
---------- ----------
         6          4
        52          0

SQL>
```

---

You said:

> I have tried with different values ... (but always got the same result)

Of course you did; all of these would return the same result:

```
select score(1)    ... contains (text, 'something', 1)
select score(100)  ... contains (text, 'something', 100)
select score(57)   ... contains (text, 'something', 57)
select score(-261) ... contains (text, 'something', -261)
```

---

There's a lot to read about Oracle Text. Here's the Table of contents (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/toc.htm); happy reading!

Comment: how such values are calculated.??                                                                         
    SC1        SC2
---------- ----------
         6          4
        52          0

Comment: `contains` is where you put the search criteria. `score` then ranks how well row (in a table) matches that criteria.

Comment: score of first row comes out tobe 6 and for second row it is 52..???  how oracle is calculating this

Comment: I don't know the algorithm that stands behind it, sorry.